# How automatically add unix timestamp for the integer field (created, modified) in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, unix-timestamp

In cakephp 2 there is a magic method which automatically fills `created` and `modified` columns with unix timestamp. But in cakephp 3 there is only `TimestampBehavior` which creates `datetime` instead of unixtime integer value `int`.

Please provide a solution to magically populate `created` and `modified` columns with type `int` by unix timestamp value in cakephp 3.

Thanks

P.S.
Here is my db table schema

```
CREATE TABLE `users_verifications_codes` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
...
`created` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [TimestampBehavior](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/timestamp.html).

> The timestamp behavior allows your table objects to update one or more timestamps on each model event. This is primarily used to populate data into created and modified fields. However, with some additional configuration, you can update any timestamp/datetime column on any event a table publishes.

```
class ArticlesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    }
}
```

Taking a look at the manual first is always a good idea. There are many other things that have changed in a similar fashion in Cake3. I recommend you to read the migration guide as well, it gives you an idea of the changes and there are many.

Comment: thanks, i'll investigate TimestampBehavior more deeply today

Answer (score 0):

[CakePHP 3.5.8] The `created` and `modified` columns had `BIGINT` types in the database of the application I'm converting from CakePHP 2.x

Ended up using the `beforeSave()` method in the `Models\ModelnameTable.php`

```
public function beforeSave($event, $entity, $options)
{
    if ($entity -> modified instanceof Time) {
        $entity -> modified = $entity -> modified -> toUnixString();
    }

    if ($entity->created instanceof Time) {
        $entity->created = $entity->created->toUnixString();
    }
}
```